# Selecting cells that hold the same values as opposed to ID in MySQL/phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please kindly point me in the right direction?

Given tables:

```
actor_uri_address
---------------------
| ID | URI | Address|
---------------------
|    |     |        |
---------------------

actor_full_name_opc
-----------------------------------------------
| ID | Given Name | Surname | Outward Postcode|
-----------------------------------------------
|    |            |         |                 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I am trying produce a table that contains actor URI, first names, surnames and addresses of actors living at the same addresses on the list (I do not need to supply the address at query time, rather the duplicate values in the address column) on phpMyAdmin.

Below is my query construct so far. Despite all efforts, I have only been able to get it to run and return the entire URIs, first names, surnames and addresses. I am totally stuck on how to have it narrow down to only the actors living at the same address.

Thanking you in advance.

```
SELECT
    `actor_uri_address`.`URI`,
    `actor_full_name_opc`.`Given Name`,
    `actor_full_name_opc`.`Surname`,
    `actor_uri_address`.`Address`
FROM
    `actor_uri_address`
LEFT JOIN `actor_full_name_opc` ON `actor_full_name_opc`.`ID` = `actor_uri_address`.`ID`
GROUP BY
    `actor_uri_address`.`URI`,
    `actor_full_name_opc`.`Given Name`,
    `actor_full_name_opc`.`Surname`,
    `actor_uri_address`.`Address`
```

Comment: Do you want all actors living at an address you specify?

Comment: Hi Salmon, I just want it to output a list of actor URIs, first names, surnames and addresses that share an address with one or more actors. Any advice, please?

Comment: 1 - work out the addresses HAVING (did you see what I did there) more than 1 actors, 2- join actors to those addresses.

Comment: Hi again Salmon, firstly, thank you for getting back to me. Yes, I thought about that because I had already worked out the address that have more than one actors with the query below but I was a significant challenge to join in the allied actors. I will fiddle a bit more and see what I come up with but if you want to be a bit more explanatory with the query before, then I will also appreciate it.

SELECT `actor_uri_address`.`Address`
FROM `actor_uri_address`
GROUP BY actor_uri_address.Address
HAVING COUNT(`actor_uri_address`.`Address`)>1

Comment: See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157002/selecting-matching-cells-that-hold-the-same-values-as-opposed-to-id-in-mysql-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using (hopefully similar data)

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Middlenames` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gender` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dod` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Warning_flag` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Worth` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `customer_address` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line4` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line5` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

truncate table customer;
insert into  customer values
(1,1,'Mr','fname1',null,'lname1','m','1990-01-01',null,null,null),
(2,1,'Mrs','fname1',null,'lname1','f','1990-01-01',null,null,null),
(3,1,'Mrs','fname1',null,'lname1','f','1990-01-01',null,null,null);
truncate table customer_address;
insert into customer_address values
(1,1,1,'Line1','Line2','Line3','Line4','Line5','pc1'),
(2,1,2,'Line1','Line2','Line3','Line4','Line5','pc1'),
(3,1,3,'Line1','Line2','Line3','Line4','Line5','pc2');
```

So if I want to find the number of customers in the same postcode

```
MariaDB [bank]> select ca.postcode, count(*) obs
    -> from customer_address ca
    -> group by ca.postcode ;
+----------+-----+
| postcode | obs |
+----------+-----+
| pc1      |   2 |
| pc2      |   1 |
+----------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but if I want to restrict it to those having 1 or more customer

```
select ca.postcode, count(*) obs
from customer_address ca
group by ca.postcode having count(*) > 1
```

Now that I know this I can get the customers living in these postcodes

```
MariaDB [bank]> select c.id,c.title, c.firstname, c.lastname,s.obs LivingAtThisPostcode
    -> from customer c
    -> join customer_address ca on ca.Customer_id = c.id
    -> join
    -> (
    -> select ca.postcode, count(*) obs
    -> from customer_address ca
    -> group by ca.postcode having count(*) > 1
    -> ) s on s.postcode = ca.postcode ;
+------+-------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
| id   | title | firstname | lastname | LivingAtThisPostcode |
+------+-------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
|    1 | Mr    | fname1    | lname1   |                    2 |
|    2 | Mrs   | fname1    | lname1   |                    2 |
+------+-------+-----------+----------+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Salmon, I would buy you beer if could see you now. After countless efforts, I finally hit the query! Thank you so much and may you also find help whenever you need it.